# How to layout single row collection view?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom collection view cell nib which is 200 by 200. I would like to layout a single row using this custom cell in my collection view. I know how to layout multiple rows but can't get a single one to work while keeping the size of the nib! How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

This is my code

```
let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 1.0
    let paddingSpace: CGFloat = 2.0 * itemsPerRow
    let availableHeight = containerView.frame.width - paddingSpace
    let widthPerItem = availableHeight / itemsPerRow
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 4.0
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a subview inside the cell with your "hardcoded" size and set the `cell.contentView` `backgroundcolor` to whatever you like.

Then in `collectionView` itemsize make the itemsize `collectionView.frame.size.width`

That way you get a fullwidth cell with a single row, and the subview inside the cell will have whatever size/layout you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `minimumInterItemSpacing` to some big number

```
layout.minimumInterItemSpacing = CGFloat_Max;
```